# H2 procedure will throw "Parameter not set" after a few calls

Tags: java, stored-procedures, wildfly, h2

I'm coming across a weird behavior when calling procedures on an H2 database : the first few calls (1 to 3 so far) will successfully return, then the next calls will consistently throw a `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Parameter "#1" is not set;`, where the first parameter is supposedly the OUT parameter.

I've also noticed that this failure pattern is relative to the `DataSource` : multiple `DataSource`s interfacing the same H2 database will each be able to call the procedure a few times before consistently throwing the error.

It also looks like waiting long enough will enable the `Datasource` to call the procedure again. Although I'm not sure exactly how long the wait needs to be, it's at least 10 minutes.

The procedure is created with the following query :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE ALIAS ps_sleep as$$
String ps_sleep(int seconds) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
    return "DB Procedure : " + seconds + " seconds waited" ;
}
$$;
```

which is executed by the following Java code :

```
((DataSource)getJNDIResource(datasourceJndiUri)).getConnection().prepareStatement(PS_SLEEP_QUERY).execute();
```

The procedure is then called by the following Java code :

```
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) context.lookup(datasourceJndiUri);
Connection con = ds.getConnection();
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{?=call PS_SLEEP(?)}");
cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
cs.setInt(2, input_proc_timer);
cs.execute();
```

I've made sure the value of `input_proc_timer` always is an `int`.

The stacktrace is the following :

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Parameter "#1" is not set; SQL statement:
 ?=call PS_SLEEP(?)  [90012-173]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:331)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:171)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:148)
    at org.h2.expression.Parameter.checkSet(Parameter.java:80)
    at org.h2.command.Prepared.checkParameters(Prepared.java:163)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:90)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:195)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:189)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.execute(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:404)
    at my.application.SomeServlet.doGet(SomeServlet.java:49)
    [...]
```

I'm running this under wildfly 8.1.0 and its packaged H2 database, which I believe is version 1.3 (the h2 module contains a h2-1.3.173.jar). I'm using the `standalone-full.xml` configuration file, which I haven't particularly modified.

I welcome any way to fix this, and would be particularly delighted if someone could explain how this behavior occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it was a bug with this version of `h2`.

[This github issue](https://github.com/rexim/freq-parser/issues/4) put me on that track, and although I was still reproducing the error with the 1.3.170 version, upgrading to 1.4.193 fixed my problem.